# Some confusion about cloud computing's on-demand self service aspect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

So I was reading some tutorials and read that "on-demand self service" is cloud computing's characteristic. But I'm very confused because why is it specifically cloud computing's characteristic? isn't it also possible to have on-demand self service aspect from non-cloud computing as well? do ALL cloud computing services allow on-demand self service WHILE almost none of those services(services that are not cloud computing) allows on-demand self service? It sounds like saying "self service is a characteristic of diesel cars"... but GASOLINE CAR OWNERS CAN ALSO DO SELF SERVICE IF THEY CHOOSE TO!". no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The National Institute of Standards and Technology published a [special publication](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-145.pdf) (800-145) that attempts to define Cloud Computing.  Under their definition, they define that "On-demand self-service" is an essential characteristic of the cloud model.

> On-demand self-service. A consumer can unilaterally provision
>   computing capabilities, such as server time and network storage, as
>   needed automatically without requiring human interaction with each
>   service provider

Their definition doesn't preclude non-cloud technologies from also providing "on-demand self-service" but their definition does imply that a provider that wants to claim that they have a cloud computing service must have such.